# Refer to column value of nested Javascript array with React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, fixed-data-table

I have a Javascript array example that I wish to visualize in a table.

Here's the array:

```
    var dataTable = [
        {   First:    {In: "5 MB", Out: "6 MB"},
            Second:    {In: "5 MB", Out: "1 MB"},
            Other:  {In: "0.2 MB", Out: "2 MB"}
        }
    ];
```

Using `fixed-data-table` in React, I wish to put this data into a table, where First, Second and Other are rows, and IN/OUT are columns.

Say I wish to populate a field with the "in" value, and afterwards, the "Out" value. Do I refer to the nested value as `First[0].In` and `First[0].Out` to retrieve it and show it in a specific cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your structure looks like an array (`dataTable`) containing a single element that is an object with keys named `First`, `Second`, and `Other`.

To access the `In` and `Out` properties of `First`, you would reference them like so: `dataTable[0].First.In` or `dataTable[0].First.Out`.

For, `Second`, you would follow the same pattern: `dataTable[0].Second.In`, etc.

Or, why not store the reference to `dataTable[0]` as a variable if you're going to be accessing its properties repeatedly?

```
var toShow = dataTable[0];
console.log(toShow.First.In);
console.log(toShow.Other.Out);
```

That should give you the general idea. You're indexing an array and then using an object's keys to access the data you want.

It looks to me like `dataTable` does not need to be an array at all if it's going to contain a single object with fixed keys; perhaps you want it to be an array of objects instead so you can index each one separately? That's up to you though as either way will work.